# IOS - Difference between DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) and perform(_:with:afterDelay:) with 0 delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, grand-central-dispatch, foundation

I realized that there is a difference between using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now())` and `perform(_:with:afterDelay:0)` when main queue is "busy".

Note that `perform(_:with:afterDelay:)` is called from main queue in my situation.

Seem like `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now())` performs the task immediately at the next run loop without caring about main queue but `perform(_:with:afterDelay:)` with 0 delay will wait and perform the task only when main queue is "free" (maybe it won't be called at the next run loop).

According to Apple document for [perform(_:with:afterDelay:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416176-perform)

> Specifying a delay of 0 does not necessarily cause the selector to be performed immediately. The selector is still queued on the thread’s run loop and performed as soon as possible.

I'm not sure that I understand them right so could anyone help me to explain exactly what is the difference under the hood between them? What does **performed as soon as possible** mean?

I found a same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112182/dispatch-after-versus-performselector-afterdelay) but seem like it's not what I want.

Comment: Guess: main.asyncAfter runs on Main Thread whereas perform method comes under NSObject and according to docs it executes on current thread (doesn't mean Main Thread, it can be any thread you which you have initialized the NSObject). May be you want to perform some action after some delay in other thread. however if you want to make sure you want to run on main thread then there is another method performSelector(onMainThread:with:waitUntilDone:modes:) but it doesn't provide delay

Comment: @SahilManchanda Thank you for suggestion and pointing out problem about calling `perform(_:with:afterDelay:)` on main queue. I forgot to mention it in the question. I have updated my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created this standalone test to explore this topic.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @objc func test1(_ info: Any) {
        guard let str = info as? String else { return }
        sleep(1)
        print(str)

        if str != "selector 3" {
            self.perform(#selector(test1), with: "selector 3", afterDelay: 0)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
            sleep(1)
            print("dispatch 4 queued by \(str)")
        }

    }


    @IBAction func test(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("begin test")

        self.perform(#selector(test1), with: "selector 1", afterDelay: 0)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
                sleep(1)
                print("dispatch 3")
            }
            sleep(1)
            print("dispatch 1")
        }

        self.perform(#selector(test1), with: "selector 2", afterDelay: 0)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
            sleep(1)
            print("dispatch 2")
        }

        print("end test")
    }

}
```

Resulting output:

```
begin test
end test
dispatch 1
dispatch 2
selector 1
selector 2
dispatch 3
dispatch 4 queued by selector 1
dispatch 4 queued by selector 2
selector 3
selector 3
dispatch 4 queued by selector 3
dispatch 4 queued by selector 3
```

---

**Things to observe:**

1. `begin test` and `end test` print before any other output showing that both `perform(_:with:afterDelay:)` and `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` are queued and run later.
2. The first two `DispatchQueue`s run before the `perform`s even though they are queued in a different order.
3. All of the prints happen one second apart meaning they are all being run on the same queue waiting for the previous to finish.
4. `dispatch 3` doesn't jump ahead of `selector 1` and `selector 2` even though it is queued before `dispatch 1` prints.

---

**Conclusions:**

1. Both `Dispatch.main.asyncAfter` and `perform(_:with:afterDelay:)` queue their selector/closure to be performed later.  Since you are running `perform(_:with:afterDelay:)` on the main thread, it uses the main queue for its scheduling.
2. For some unknown (to me) reason, `Dispatch.main.asyncAfter(0)` calls are queued before `perform(_:with:afterDelay:0)` calls when queued in the same run loop.  Note: if any delay at all is added to the `Dispatch.main.asyncAfter`, it will then be queued after the `perform(_:with:afterDelay:)`.  Try using `.now() + .milliseconds(1)`, for example.
3. **performed as soon as possible** is just another way to say they are queued and processed in queue order.  Depending on how long the tasks take in the queue ahead, it might take many runs of the run loop before a task is finally handled.

Comment: You need to perform some tests from another threads as well in order to achieve reasonable results.

Comment: @dvp.petrov Why? OP is asking about the difference when called from the main thread.

Comment: @vacawama Thank you for great example. It totally explained what I'm talking about. Do you have any conclusion with these 4 above things?

Comment: @trungduc, I added some conclusions.